# DBPedia SPARQL query "NaturalPerson" brings back no data?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, dbpedia, rdfs

The following brings back a list of people - relating to a pages about Podcasts:

```
SELECT *
WHERE
{
?person rdf:type dbo:Person,foaf:Person,schema:Person;
        rdfs:label ?name;       
        dbo:wikiPageWikiLink dbr:Podcast.
FILTER(lang(?name)='en').
}
```

Run it [here](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?query=SELECT%20*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fperson%20rdf%3Atype%20dbo%3APerson%2Cfoaf%3APerson%2Cschema%3APerson%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fname%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3AwikiPageWikiLink%20dbr%3APodcast.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28lang%28%3Fname%29%3D%27en%27%29.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

But this one brings back nothing:

```
SELECT *
WHERE
{
?person rdf:type dbo:Person,foaf:Person,schema:Person, dul:NaturalPerson;
        rdfs:label ?name;       
        dbo:wikiPageWikiLink dbr:Podcast.
FILTER(lang(?name)='en').
}
```

Run it [here](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?query=SELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%3Fperson%20rdf%3Atype%20dbo%3APerson%2Cfoaf%3APerson%2Cschema%3APerson%2C%20dul%3ANaturalPerson%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fname%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3AwikiPageWikiLink%20dbr%3APodcast.%0D%0AFILTER%28lang%28%3Fname%29%3D%27en%27%29.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Am I using [dul:NaturalPerson](http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/dul/DUL.owl#NaturalPerson) in the wrong way?
Checking a couple of examples, I can't seem to see why it is different to others.
For instance:

https://dbpedia.org/page/Joe_Rogan has all `dbo:Person`,`foaf:Person`,`schema:Person`, `dul:NaturalPerson` properties present.

Background:

I'm trying to narrow down my search - some of the pages aren't actually people, they are the Podcasts themselves. In doing this - I'm trying to add in various 'Person' objects from different vocabs - although I fear this won't achieve my objectives (since I can't seem to find a differentiating property) - but in doing so - I stumbled upon this.

Comment: Prefixes are just convenience. The problem you've seen now that it's best practice to make your query self-contained, i.e. put all the prefixes directly in your query instead of relying on some pre-registered prefixes. Especially, when you would use your query in some other SPARQL engine, the parser would fail because it doesn't know the prefix declarations. And those prefix declarations are not fixed (though there is some common-sense e.g. for rdf,rdfs, etc.)

Comment: See the list of registered prefixes for the DBpedia Virtuoso backend: https://dbpedia.org/sparql/?help=nsdecl - the `dul:` prefix is missing the trailing `#`, that's why using the pre-registered `dul:` fails to return anything as it would resolve to `http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/dul/DUL.owlNaturalPerson` -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the RDF/N3 serialization of [Joe Rogan](https://dbpedia.org/data/Joe_Rogan.n3), you will find:

```
@prefix dbo:    <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> .
@prefix foaf:   <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> .
@prefix ns14:   <http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/dul/DUL.owl#> .
```

The same prefixes appears in the turtle serialization. The `dul` prefix is never defined explicitly. I don't know the reason of this but this could explain your empty result.

Moreover you should note that in the [DBPeadia ontology](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/OntologyClass:Person) there is an `owl:equivalentClass` relation between `foaf:Person`, `schema:Person`, `wikidata:Q215627`, `wikidata:Q5` and `dul:NaturalPerson`.

Comment: Thanks - I have upvoted - but not yet accepted - as it would be good for others to help with the explanation of the 'dul:' prefix.

Comment: @monojohnny Maybe you should ask a question on the [data quality section of the DBPedia forum](https://forum.dbpedia.org/c/data/data-quality/10) and add a link to it here.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a SPARQL Query Solution page](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix%20dbo%3A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%20%0D%0Aprefix%20foaf%3A%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%20%0D%0Aprefix%20schema%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%3E%20%0D%0Aprefix%20dul%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.ontologydesignpatterns.org%2Font%2Fdul%2FDUL.owl%23%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%3Fperson%20rdf%3Atype%20dbo%3APerson%2Cfoaf%3APerson%2Cschema%3APerson%2C%20dul%3ANaturalPerson%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fname%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3AwikiPageWikiLink%20dbr%3APodcast.%0D%0AFILTER%28lang%28%3Fname%29%3D%27en%27%29.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=10000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on) that provides results.
[Here's the associated SPARQL Query Definition page](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=prefix%20dbo%3A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%20%0D%0Aprefix%20foaf%3A%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%20%0D%0Aprefix%20schema%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%3E%20%0D%0Aprefix%20dul%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.ontologydesignpatterns.org%2Font%2Fdul%2FDUL.owl%23%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%3Fperson%20rdf%3Atype%20dbo%3APerson%2Cfoaf%3APerson%2Cschema%3APerson%2C%20dul%3ANaturalPerson%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fname%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3AwikiPageWikiLink%20dbr%3APodcast.%0D%0AFILTER%28lang%28%3Fname%29%3D%27en%27%29.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=10000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on) which shows incorporation of namespace prefix declarations that solve the problem.

```
prefix dbo:    <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
prefix foaf:   <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> 
prefix dul:   <http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/dul/DUL.owl#>
```

Comment: Great. Thank you! Also - what a great feature of linked-in online data - where we can share not only the code, and results - but the in effect the same environment. Brilliant.